# How can I remove characters before and after a text in a chain of characters with Grep, knowing that text is produced through a variable?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm using

```
grep 'name=>' log.txt | cut -d\   -f3
```

I get this kind of result:

```
name=>"Faya-Largeau",
name=>"Paris",
name=>"Madrid",
```

name is the output of a variable (I have a long list of cities like this)

I would like to get only "Faya-Largeau" or "Paris" or "Madrid"
So I need to exclude both name=> and , before and after a city between brackets.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "is the output of a variable"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input and ii) the output you want. We cannot help you parse your data if we cannot see what the data look like. Also add your operating system since the `grep` you have available will depend on that and there are significant differences.

Answer (score 1):

The primary use of the `grep` utility is to extract lines matching a particular regular expression.  Some non-standard implementations of `grep` can also extract substrings from lines, but this is encroaching on the domain of the `sed` editor, commonly used for performing scripted edits on lines in files or text streams.

Using standard `sed` to first delete all lines that do not contain the substring `name=>` followed by a double-quoted string and capture the double-quoted string.  Then substitute the matched line with the double-quoted string.

```bash
sed -e '/.*name=>\("[^"]*"\).*/!d' -e 's//\1/' log.txt
```

(This is supposed to be run directly on your original file.)

The first expression, `/.*name=>\("[^"]*"\).*/!d`, deletes all lines that do not match the given regular expression. It also captures the double-quoted string in `\1`.

The second expression, `s//\1/`, replaces, on the remaining lines, the bit of the line that matched the previous regular expression with the captured double-quoted string.

Comment: Why not the more idiomatic and straightforward `sed -n 's/.*name=>\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/p'`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hmm... This was probably during a time when I thought using `-n` was a bit inelegant. I may come back to this answer tomorrow or in the weekend and revise it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$ grep 'name=>' log.txt | cut -d'"' -f2
```

`|` pipes the output of `grep` to the input of `cut`.

`cut -d'"' -f2` cuts each line of input in fields separated by the character `"` and extracts the second field.

If you want to keep the `"` character around the names of the city, this might not work though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` instead of `grep` and `cut`.  For example:

```
awk -F'"' '/name=>/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: note]
As far as this can be just a capture of what is between double quotes:

##### Input

```
$ cat file
name=>"Brie Comte Robert",
name=>"Montcuq",
name=>"Faya-Largeau",
name=>"Paris",
name=>"Madrid",
```

##### With just `grep`

```
$ grep -oE '"[^"]+"'  file
$ grep -o  '"[^"]\+"' file
```

##### Using `GNU` `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\042([^\"]+)\042"} {print $1}' file
```

##### Output

```
"Brie Comte Robert"
"Montcuq"
"Faya-Largeau"
"Paris"
"Madrid"
```